# Javascript Schema, added keys don't show up

Tags: javascript, mongodb, mongoose

I've run into a problem where some javascript schema keys with **type: Schema.Types.ObjectId** when added to my schema don't display when I do a console.log.

Its driving me crazy. I can't figure out the problem.  I've tried deleting the database but that doesn't help.

```
const FarmSchema = new Schema({
  name: {
    type: String,
    required: [true, 'Farm must have a name!']
  },
  author: {
    type: Schema.Types.ObjectId,
    ref: 'User',
  },
  description: {
    type: String
  },
  images: [imageSchema],
  location: {
    type: String
  },
  products: [{
    type: Schema.Types.ObjectId,
    ref: 'Product'
  }],
  reviews: [
    {
        type: Schema.Types.ObjectId,
        ref: 'Review'
    }
  ],
  website: {
    type: String,
    required: false
  },
}, opts);
```

When I do a console.log(farm); the other keys display for the variable, author won't when I do a <%= console.log(farm); %> in ejs. I have a user schema it has just one key **email**

The console.log displays this:

```
{
  products: [],
  reviews: [],
  _id: 612fd96ab7f9394de07b4c1b,
  name: 'Lyman Orchards',
  description: "We're here, we're open and we're a great alternative to the large supermarkets. As a local farm store, Lyman Orchards' realizes the importance of supplying fresh local food to families in Connecticut. We are open 9 to 6 every day so please stop in or you can call in your take-out order for any of our menu items including prepared meals from the deli, bakery items, fresh produce and more. Our unique market has become known throughout Connecticut and beyond as a favorite destination for family fun and great food! The enticing aroma of fresh baked products fills our market all day long. Every day, all day long, fresh pies, apple cider donuts, muffins, cookies, breads, pastries, and many other desserts are made in our Farm Kitchen Bakery. Stop by our store today! We are located in Middlefield, Connecticut, near Middletown and Durham.",
  location: '32 Reeds Gap Rd, Middlefield, CT 06455',
  website: 'http://lymanorchards.com/',
  images: [],
  __v: 0
}
```

I removed the opts and it still isn't displaying author. What dependencies could be causing this? I am using connect-mongo 3.2.0 because I am reusing code from a different source and there was an issue with  mongostore.  All the rest of my npm i packages are up to date.

I just updated mongodb and mongoose but it still isn't working.

I changed the author field to a string and added an input on the form to add author and it adds the author and author is visible in console.log.  For some reason there is a problem with Schema.Types.ObjectId.

Sorry guys, I am a newb when it comes to js, I took the web developer boot camp by colt steele and tried reusing the final project but it definitely doesn't use the most up to date packages as the code is a year old and when trying to use the newest dependencies by removing the package and package-lock json files to use newest versions it throws errors.

Comment: Post relevant code and the problematic output, as text.

Comment: Now [edit the question](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/69019917/edit) yourself and add relevant code that causes the issue, together with the output.

Comment: you sure your dependencies are correct - your schema creation code is working, take a look at this codesandbox - https://codesandbox.io/s/mongoose-sandbox-forked-g86sn?file=/index.js . Or your opts might be causing it. More info please